# Correct strptime format for Input Type Time on Rails 4

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, web-applications, strptime

Want to use the

```
<input name=attendance[something] type="time">
```

For time input. However cant make it seem to match with a Datetime object; for manipulation before insertion to ActiveRecord

```
myTimeIn = Time.strptime(params[attendance][something],"%H:%M")
```

keeps getting

```
invalid strptime format - `%H:%M'
```

What is the correct format for a input type=time field?

Comment: Did you see the format of params[attendance][something] ?

Comment: @Manikandan  "something"=>"18:52"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the value of `params[attendance][something]` may be blank or not of the correct format.  You could do something like below to avoid the error:

```
t = params[attendance][something]
myTimeIn = Time.strptime(t,"%H:%M") if t =~ /\d{1,2}:\d{2}/
```

As per this [HTML example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_time), the value produced by `<input/>` of type `time` is `HH:MM`